# SceneBuilder Kit crippled by Gluon charm hidden dependency?

Tags: scenebuilder, gluon

Downloaded Gluon Scene Builder Kit. Upon execution the program will crash during "EditController" creation - instancing.

Tried older versions and scoured the net to no avail. The range of options are (to me) limited as there are hidden dependencies is closed libs.

public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        **EditorController editor_controller =  new EditorController();**
         ...
         ...
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){ launch(args); }
}

I expected to see at the least the content pane but instead got:

"java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lau

...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 13 more"

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by adding "charm-glisten-5.0.2.jar" to the project references (I'm using IntelliJ btw). Which Jar is NOT referenced anywhere on - in the SceneBuilder kit download download section, or the site.

So, if one wishes to expose scene builder in YOUR app, NOT simply to integrate it into your IDE, then make sure you add the above jar as a reference to your project. It can be found in the repo at https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm-glisten/5.02/

Comment: If you use manual download of the kit, you will be missing all the dependencies, and you will find out at compile (charm) or maybe runtime (aether dependencies). The list is quite big ([dependencies](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/blob/master/build.gradle#L40)). If you go through Maven Central (for instance 'com.gluonhq.scenebuilder:scenebuilder-kit:10.0.0') then all the transitive dependencies will be resolved automatically.

Comment: Thank you Jose would have been nice, if it were mentioned it somewhere on the download page. Would have saved yours truly about five hours of frustration.. Again thank you, this (your comment) could save someone some frustration in the future.

Comment: i was using version 11 of the kit, it doesn't seem to have hit the repos yet. Thanks for you help though.